# How to detect the 3rd, 4th, 5th letter in a string C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, detection

I have a `string` structured like:

```
string s = "0R   0R  20.0V  100.0V  400.0R    60R  70.0R";
```

My question is, how would I detect only the *3rd*, *4th*, *5th* letter through if statements like so:

```
3rd letter = V
4th letter = V
5th letter = R

//pseudocode below 
if (3rd letter in string == V)
{
   return true;
}

if (4th letter in string == V)
{
   return true;
}

if (5th letter in string == R)
{
   return true;
}
```

or through print statements:

```
3rd letter = V
4th letter = V
5th letter = R

// Pseudocode below:
Console.WriteLine("3rd Letter"); //should return V
Console.WriteLine("4th Letter"); //should return V
Console.WriteLine("5th Letter"); //should return R
```

I was thinking of using a foreach loop to loop through the string but I am unsure how to detect when it is the *3rd, 4th, 5th* letter, I know that *regex* may help but I'm not sure *how to implement* the expression

```
string s = "0R   0R  20.0V  100.0V  400.0R    60R  70.0R";

foreach(char c in s)
{
   // detect 3rd 4th 5th letter in here
}
```

Comment: `string[] letters = Regex.Matches(s, "[A-Z]").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();`

Comment: Just us the index operator. `s[0]` is the 0th char, `s[1]` is the 1st char, `s[2]` is the 2nd, etc.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "detect the 3rd letter"? Do you mean, ignoring anything that isn't categorized as a letter, I want the 3rd of those characters from the string?

Comment: So in the string: `0R  0R  20.0V...` I want to detect the third letter which in this case is V

Comment: Try @DmitryBychenko's example above. Then use `letters[2]` to get the 3rd letter.

Comment: String will always be in the same pattern or letters places can be changed?

Comment: Yes, the string is always the same pattern, only need to detect 3rd, 4th, 5th letter

Comment: Thank you @Dmitry Bychenko, the answer worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's extract / match letters either with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

string[] letters = s
 .Where(c => c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
 .Select(c => c.ToString())
 .ToArray();
```

or *regular expressions*:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string[] letters = Regex
  .Matches(s, "[A-Z]")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(m => m.Value)
  .ToArray();
```

Then you can put as easy as

```
string letter3d = letters[3 - 1];  // - 1 : arrays are zero based
string letter4th = letters[4 - 1];
string letter5th = letters[5 - 1];
```